# Seedbank, nothing happens when doing rake db:seed anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rake

I just installed seedbank gem : https://github.com/james2m/seedbank which is *exactly* what I was looking for! (I'm actually surprised this kind of feature is not in the core Rails, but anyway, thanks james2m)

My problem is, nothing happens when doing `rake db:seed -v`. Not even the former seeds.rb generation.

I guess this is the best place to report the issue.

I don't really know what information will be useful to help me, so here I go, without order:

1- Content of /db:

```
/db
 | candidate.seeds.rb
 | item.seeds.rb
 | seeds.rb
 | user.seeds.rb
```

2- Gem file extract

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem "seedbank", "~> 0.2.1"
```

and I've run `bundle install` with no error.

3- Version numbers

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.13
$ rake -V
rake, version 10.0.4
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you sorted this out or not but I think your directory structure was/is incorrect

```
/db/seeds.rb    (runs on all environments) 
/db/seeds/candidate.seeds.rb
/db/seeds/item.seeds.rb
/db/seeds/user.seeds.rb
```

These will run for all environments.  If you only want development then do this structure instead

```
/db/seeds.rb  (runs on all environments)   
/db/seeds/development/candidate.seeds.rb
/db/seeds/development/item.seeds.rb
/db/seeds/development/user.seeds.rb
```

Comment: I did sorted it out on github: https://github.com/james2m/seedbank/issues/25 the explanation being the one you gave here ! Thanks !